# VBA Error: unable to set the formulaarray property of the range class

Tags: excel, vba

I recently tried using this array formula through VBA but kept getting this error. How can I resolve this issue?

This is the line I have problem with.

```
YY.Cells(i, "C").FormulaArray = "=VLOOKUP($A" & i & "&" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Value & ",CHOOSE({1,2},'XX'!$B$4:$B$" & rowCount & "&'XX'!$H$4:$H$" & rowCount & ",'XX'!$E$4:$E$ & rowCount),2,0)"
```

Comment: Your last `& rowCount` is inside the double quotes. Currently: `'XX'!$E$4:$E$ & rowCount),2,0)"`. Should be: `'XX'!$E$4:$E$" & rowCount & "),2,0)"`

Comment: Oh right, thanks. I missed that part. but still got the same error.

Comment: What is this extra `&` doing in here: `$A" & i & "&" ` the one between double quotes.

Comment: I would put that whole formula into the immediate window and see what's wrong with it. `debug.print "=VLOOKUP($A" & i & "&" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Value & ",CHOOSE({1,2},'XX'!$B$4:$B$" & rowCount & "&'XX'!$H$4:$H$" & rowCount & ",'XX'!$E$4:$E$ & rowCount),2,0)"` right before you set it. Something is wrong with whatever formula this is producing and causing VBA to error out.

Comment: It would be something like this

"=VLOOKUP($A3 & ""201708"",CHOOSE({1,2},'XX'!$B$4:$B$7669 &'XX'!$H$4:$H$7669,'XX'!$E$4:$E$7669),2,0)"

Comment: Does the userform1.textbox1.value have the double quotes around it or is it just passing in a string free of quotes? I think, again, an output of the actual result of the string concatenation would make the issue visible.

Comment: Oh I see, it was a mistake on my part. Fixed.